# how to remove Nan Value in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, nan

```
missing_values=['NAN','NaN','Nan',"na",np.nan]    

df=pd.read_csv('train.csv',na_values=missing_values )

df.fillna(df['column_name'].mean())

df.isnull().sum(axis = 0)
```

also tried to `dropna` nothing seems to work `df` still has missing values

Comment: Well, which missing values are still present, and how were they encoded in the CSV?

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
 index = np.isnan(df)
 df = np.delete(df,index)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do the `fillna` please assign it back or add `inplace`

```
df.fillna(df['column_name'].mean(),inplace=True)
df=df.fillna(df['column_name'].mean())
```